# Do outside-funded graduate students normally have TA or grading responsibilities in the US?

Tags: graduate-school, mathematics, united-states, funding, teaching-assistant

Assuming a student has full funding from an outside source. Do the TA and grading responsibilities become optional?

Comment: Some departments require a period as a TA because it is seen as providing experience in teaching that is generally required for many jobs.

Comment: My national university sends students with a full scholarship and stipend to study in the US. Therefore students do not require any funding that most students typically require from the schools they apply to.

Comment: @JonCuster Really?  Where?  I don't know any math departments in the US that mandate (as opposed to strongly encourage) this.

Comment: @Kimball - many moons ago in an engineering department they had everyone be a TA. Just part of the program, everyone did it in the first few years, no big deal. And, yes, even those with external funding (including the IBM fellows getting their IBM salary).

Comment: @JonCuster, I assume such "requirements" come with the usual perks; tuition forgiveness and a stipend. Otherwise it is indentured servitude. Even scheduling it arbitrarily seems very wrong.

Comment: @Buffy - of course. All PhD students were funded, internally through TA or RA, or external (again, we had a few industry fellows -paid by their company to get a PhD - or by various industry fellowships). But doing a turn as a TA was part of the gig.

Comment: @Kimball My non-math dept does.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- + Jon Custer Hmm... maybe it's more common in non-math departments then?  That said, in math departments there are relatively few people who get full external funding, and maybe there are such requirements but I've never heard about them.

Comment: @Kimball That actually surprises me, as I would have thought more math departments would have been focused on preparing PhD students to work in departments that might teach a lot of classes for the university.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Normally," no. But you should never make any assumptions and always get a written statement of your obligations to the department. Some math departments require some teaching as a part of the program, but how much varies a lot. It might also be the case that if you don't have instructional duties, then you don't get office space.

Comment: My neuroscience PhD had a TA requirement as well, regardless of outside funding, but just for a minimum of one semester. Most students in that program are primarily funded by RAships, so a TA requirement was both to benefit the department, in that there was otherwise not a natural source of TAs, and to benefit the students, to ensure that everyone would have at least a semester of teaching experience on their resume by the time they graduated.

Comment: Only giving TAs office space is lame, what? I haven't heard of that.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Yup, even for doctoral students. Some places are really strapped for space.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I do not have any handy references, but I am pretty sure there are office-less tenured professors.  Office space is a finite resource.

Answer (score 2):

While it is now several decades past and details may have changed, I was a student in a Tier 1 US research university math department with multiple years of (so-called, see below) "full" external funding.

The tone of your questions suggests you would prefer not to have TA or grading responsibilities with such funding. There is, of course, good reason for this if those responsibilities are extensive or onerous. However, in mathematics in particular, even the most successful researchers end up doing some teaching during their careers, and training/experience as a grad student to do this is helpful. So I would strive to negotiate a *reduction* in teaching/service time, but not try to skip it altogether.

As a formal point, while this may have changed, in my time many private research universities nominally charged quite significant Ph.D. program tuition, which they "waived" (i.e., it was a fiction on paper only) for all recipients of internal or external funding, which was ultimately everyone in the program. Therefore, technically, the department may well insist on some labor from you as a condition of the "tuition waiver" part of your "support". Or you could theoretically find that your external funding doesn't go as far as intended...this is why I put "full" in quotes at the top of the answer.

Comment: It’s not that I prefer not to have these responsibilities, but that I would like the option to reduce them if I needed like you said. I have seen some high ranked programs where the tuition was waived for all accepted students. I wonder how that affects the admission of someone who would not need any funding since not requiring any funds usually increases the likelihood of being accepted.

Answer (score 0):

It entirely depends on the department, but most likely no. In the US, students can be funded on an internal or external fellowship (like you've described), on a research assistantship (i.e. on a specific grant), or as a TA.

However, I say most likely no because it is possible the department will require some time as a TA as teaching experience before graduation.

Comment: I think the teaching experience would be quite valuable as a graduate student. My concern was if I was taking some particularly difficult courses and wanted some more time that semester.

Comment: @Delta_Epsilon The timing of the TAship would be entirely up to your department. If it's mandated, I would guess that they would schedule it for a different semester than when people usually take difficult classes.